# How to set the drawable to for android app for multiple resolution?

Tags: android, drawable

I am developing android app which has lots of images. It's a korean app.
I want to support maximum number of resolution possible.
So I created 4 different folder(ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi) for drawable as the google doc stated.
Now my problem is that my app work on all most all device perfectly but In korea there is device [Pantech Vega LTE M](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=3439&c=pantech_vega_racer_2_lte_im-a830s_sky) which is giving lots of trouble

It's resolution is of xhdpi category but still in this device my app shows images from mdpi and it show bigger than it resolution. So half of the image is displays compressed.

So I am not getting how to set the drawables for this device. Do i need to add separate drawable folder to match this resolution.

If i changes the images in mdpi folder than it will create problem for other resolution.

Beside how many folder I need to add make my app compatible with every possible resolution available.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because that device runs Android 2.3 Gingerbread where the X-Large configuration was yet *not supported* since that resolution was supported beginning with Adroid 3.0 afaik.

**Edit:**
Looks like the xhdpi was supported since API level 9, and the configuration specs from your device looks like a normal - large screen with xhdpi. So the only workaround that I could think of is creating those folders within your drawables.

Comment: well on the specs of the device seem to be running 2.3x eventough it upgraded to ICS, I suggest you check the device density as mentioned below, because so far this seems like a bug on the custom ROM for that device.